# Save image/jpeg type from REST service to user's machine using Jquery

Tags: jquery, rest

I have a REST service built using WCF and it sets the response type as "*image/jpeg*".
This REST service is consumed by JQuery using "*$.ajax*" method.

How can I make JQuery present the "*Save as*" browser dialog to user and let him save the image.

Comment: Simply change the current URL to that of the image you want to download.  You'll also need a `Content-Disposition` header set in the HTTP response to suggest that it should be a download.

Comment: try `application/oct-stream` header instead?

Comment: I have used the following code in WCF.
`WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";`

also I have tried _application/octet-stream_.

But When I try to set the image to a hidden IFrame, the image just gets set to the iframe instead of the browser showing the dialog.